# Vanilla JS quantity increment and decrement buttons update only one input

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to work out why my quantity increase and decrease buttons are working for only one input. Here is a link for the js fiddle and the code also below

https://jsfiddle.net/c7dm2oev/

```
var value,
quantityAmount,
increase,
decrease,
quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity-container');

function init() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++ ) {
        quantityAmount = quantity[i].getElementsByClassName('quantity-amount')[0];
        increase = quantity[i].getElementsByClassName('increase')[0];
        decrease = quantity[i].getElementsByClassName('decrease')[0];
        increase.addEventListener('click', increaseValue);
        decrease.addEventListener('click', decreaseValue);
    }
};

function increaseValue(event) {
    value = parseInt(quantityAmount.value, 10);

    console.log(quantityAmount, quantityAmount.value);

    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    quantityAmount.value = value;
}

function decreaseValue(event) {
    value = parseInt(quantityAmount.value, 10);

    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (value > 0) value--;

    quantityAmount.value = value;
}

init();
```

and the html

<

```
div class="quantity-container">
<input type="text" class="quantity-amount" name="" value="1" />
<button class="decrease" type="button" title="Decrease Quantity>-</button>
    <button class="increase" type="button" title="Increase Quantity">+</button>
</div>
<div class="quantity-container">
    <input type="text" class="quantity-amount" name="" value="1" />
    <button class="decrease" type="button" title="Decrease Quantity">-</button>
    <button class="increase" type="button" title="Increase Quantity">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you need to fix:

- The `increaseValue` and `decreaseValue` functions always act on the input that is stored in the `quantityAmount` global variable. After the `init()`, that variable will always be set to the last input on the page. Instead, you could pass the input to modify as a parameter to these functions.
- Inside the `init()`, the variable `i` will suffer the same bug (will be set to to `quantity.length` after `init()` ran. To fix that, you could bundle everything in the `for` loop in a function, which will create a new variable scope and thus avoid the aforementioned problem.

Here's a version in which I have made these modifications: https://jsfiddle.net/c7dm2oev/17/

I have:

- removed the unneeded global variables
- wrote the `createBindings` function to package the data binding logic for one quantity control
- made `increaseValue` and `decreaseValue` take the quantityAmount input as a parameter

#### Edit

Now that the `increaseValue` and `decreaseValue` are no longer event handlers, the `event` parameters can be safely removed: https://jsfiddle.net/c7dm2oev/25/

The final code:

<-- language: lang-js -->

```
var value,
    quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity-container');

        function createBindings(quantityContainer) {
      var quantityAmount = quantityContainer.getElementsByClassName('quantity-amount')[0];
      var increase = quantityContainer.getElementsByClassName('increase')[0];
      var decrease = quantityContainer.getElementsByClassName('decrease')[0];
      increase.addEventListener('click', function () { increaseValue(quantityAmount); });
      decrease.addEventListener('click', function () { decreaseValue(quantityAmount); });
    }

    function init() {
        for (var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++ ) {
                    createBindings(quantity[i]);
        }
    };

    function increaseValue(quantityAmount) {
        value = parseInt(quantityAmount.value, 10);

        console.log(quantityAmount, quantityAmount.value);

        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        quantityAmount.value = value;
    }

    function decreaseValue(quantityAmount) {
        value = parseInt(quantityAmount.value, 10);

        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value > 0) value--;

        quantityAmount.value = value;
    }

    init();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-container'))
  .map(function (container) {
    return {
      input: container.querySelector('.quantity-amount'),
      decrease: container.querySelector('.decrease'),
      increase: container.querySelector('.increase'),
      get value () { return parseInt(this.input.value); },
      set value (v) { this.input.value = v; }
    }
  })
  .forEach(function (item) {
    item.decrease.addEventListener('click', function () { 
      item.value -= 1;
    });
    item.increase.addEventListener('click', function () {
      item.value += 1;
    });
  });
```

The problem is that you are using global variables which are reassigned in the `init()` function. In this case you do not need any global variables, since the value to increase/decrease is stored in the input.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfvzoLq8/1/)