# Edit quantity on click/text

Tags: php, html, count

how are you?

I would like to know how I can do to allow the user to edit(text) the quantity field in addition to using the + and - buttons (plus and minus). Briefly, how can i make the user enter the amount of items he wants to add to his cart. It is possible?

````
    ``` <div class="col-5 col-xs-5 col-md-2 border-bottom border-right" style=" text-align: center;"><br>
                <button product_id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn_minus rounded-circle btn btn-danger">-</button>
                <span id="qtde_txt{{ $product->id }}">0</span>
                <button product_id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn_plus rounded-circle btn btn-success"><b>+</b></button>
        </div>```
````

Many thanks!!

Comment: Hello Renan. Welcome to StackOverflow. Concerning your question, there are a number of things you can do to get a good answer. The question is currently a bit unclear, and appears to be rushed. A question should be easily understandable, otherwise you may end up with a question that remains unanswered purely because people didn't quite understand the problem. Things you could do to improve your question could be to 
1. check your gramma
2. describe what you have tried
3. describe what technologies you are using? It could be angular, but it is not all that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this (for example) with JQuery. For the particular code that you have shown, you can use the following script to do this:

```
$(".btn_plus").on("click", function()
{
    var span_element = $(this).prev(); //get the span element
    var quantity     = span_element.html(); //get the span value
    
    quantity = parseInt(quantity) + 1; //increment it
    
    span_element.html(quantity); //update the quantity in the span element
});
```

The same will go for the minus button, except that you will decrement your quantity. However, if you want the user to be able to edit the quantity just change the span into an input of type text:

`<input type="text" id="qtde_txt{{ $product->id }}" value="0" />`

But you will need to update the JQuery code I wrote above to map with the changes.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use javascript for that, there are multiple examples for a counter / number input like that.
One example: [Vanilla JS quantity increment and decrement buttons update only one input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503907/vanilla-js-quantity-increment-and-decrement-buttons-update-only-one-input)